# Fabric js: Fill and Stroke overlap which look as if element has 2 strokes

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Please have a look at the fiddle to see how it looks like there are two strokes instead of one.
http://jsfiddle.net/7jmtu1z9/2/

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
      originX: "left",
      originY: "top",
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: "black",
      hasControls: true,
      hasBorders: true,
      stroke: "blue",
      strokeWidth: 10,
      opacity: 0.5,
      objectCaching: false,
      noScaleCache: false,
      strokeUniform: true,
    }));
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

I would like for the stroke to not overlap with the shape's fill.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `paintFirst` flag to `stroke`.

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
      originX: "left",
      originY: "top",
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: "black",
      hasControls: true,
      hasBorders: true,
      stroke: "blue",
      strokeWidth: 10,
      opacity: 0.5,
      objectCaching: false,
      noScaleCache: false,
      strokeUniform: true,
      paintFirst: "stroke",
    }));
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```